# Female turtle unexpectedly laid eggs, what do I do now?

Tags: breeding, turtles, eggs

I have recently rescued a female Indian flapshell turtle. I kept it in my tank for few days. I found 9 eggs in my tank today. Can I expect babies from the eggs? How do I need to care for the eggs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not wish to have some hatchings on your hands then do not allow them to incubate by keeping them cold. If you found the animal in the wild then it may well of laid fertile eggs. If you wish to hatch the eggs then buy an egg incubator for your animal's species. Egg incubators can be bought for around $100 US Dollars on incubators.org.